# I want to host my website from my home network

Tags: networking, tomcat, router, port-forwarding

I want host my simple HTML site on my home network using Apache Tomcat 7

1. I have domain which is perfectely pointing to my router's IP Address
2. I did forward my port (Router Port) Like below Screen Shot.

[image]

3. When I am connecting to my domain name `www.example.com` in browser it’s forwarding me to my router's IP address (like `http://59.94.192.213/`) and showing TP link router page. Like above page.
4. But when I connecting address like `http://59.94.192.213:8181/` its showing me a Tomcat page. And after adding my application name `(http://59.94.192.213:8181/appName/)` I am able to see my application and access it.

Is it possible to access it via `http://www.example.com/appName/`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reach your page via http standard port you must forward also port 80 on your router.

Some routers needs special attention when you enable port 80 forwarding because you could (could!) lock yourself out from the web interface. I am not familiar with that TP-Link model, but check the documentation and backup your configuration before forwarding port 80.

In the root directory of your web server put an index.html with something like

```
<htlm><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://59.94.192.213:8181/appName/" />
</head></html>
```

or, better:

```
<htlm><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com:8181/appName/" />
</head></html>
```

That should forward whe web browser to tomcat application on the right port.

Comment: I am able to access with "http://59.94.192.215:8181/" but not with "http://www.example.in:8181/".

Comment: i have added one more antry in Vertual Server with following params. "HTTP_Server ALL 80 80 192.168.1.9". Now after firing my domain name in URL its taking me to the My Router's Ip Address but its not showing TP Link Router page. But I am able to access my Tomcat Server Using "http://59.94.192.213:8181/appName/".

Comment: If the IP address is your own, when I try to GET the home page of the IP address via HTTP on port 80 I receive a 404 (not found) error.

Check the error log of you web server

Comment: access with this "http://59.94.192.215:8181/html5/"

Comment: Are able to access this ?

Comment: Yes! I see a website